# Integrate $\oint \frac{e^z}{z^2-1}dz$ over $\gamma$ being the circle centered at $0$ of radius $2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So I need to integrate

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z^2-1}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius $2$ centered at $0$. So by the residue theorem I have that

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z^2-1}dz = 2 \pi i \bigg( \text{Res}(\frac{e^z}{z^2-1};1)+ \text{Res} (\frac{e^z}{z^2-1};-1) \bigg)= \pi i (e-e^{-1})$$

So I calculated the residues at the two points of singularity. Namely, $z=\pm 1$. Did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final answer is right, but you should write $$\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}, \pm 1\right)$$ instead of those functions. The functions you put inside does not even have singularity there.

Comment: AHA good catch, you're right!

Comment: other than that, I computed it out correctly? @Riemann

Comment: Yes. Your calculation is right.

Answer (score 0):

By using Cauchy's Integral Formula;

Let $g(z)=e^z/(z^2-1)$, and γ=C !

Let f(z) be analytic in a simply connected domain D.Then for any point $z_{0}$ in D and any simple closed path C in D that encloses $z_{0}$, $$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi if(z_{0})$$
Since the radius of the circle is 2, $r=|z|=2$
It's obvious that the circle encloses the points $z=\pm1$!
$|1|=1<2$ (checks!), $|-1|=1<2$ (checks!)

This situation emphasizes that we have to apply Cauchy's Integral Formula twice!

$(1)$
For the case $z_{0}=1$,
$$g(z) = \frac{e^z }{z^2-1}=\frac{e^z }{(z-1)(z+1)}=> f(z)= \frac{e^z }{z+1}$$
This implies that, $f(z_{0})=e/2$

So that,
$$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi if(z_{0})=2\pi i(\frac{e}{2})=i\pi e $$
$(2)$

Likewise, if the same process would be applied to the case $z_{0}=-1$,
$$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi if(z_{0})=-\frac{i\pi}{e} $$
Now it's clear that, $$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=i\pi(e-\frac{1}{e}))$$